# Cross Platform App for iOS and Android

Tags: c#

I saw this video how to make cross platform App: https://youtu.be/CUROh7r4qrM?t=1311

But I only have Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native) and not Blank.App Portable.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose whether you want Blank App or not in the next step of the project creation wizard.

[image: New Cross-Platform Solution Wizard]